# tensorflow conflicts with anaconda and python versions

Tags: tensorflow

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2323e6a3e8e5> in <module>
----> 1 import keras
      2 from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, ConvLSTM2D, BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed, Conv2D
      3 from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
      4 from keras_layer_normalization import LayerNormalization
      5 from IPython.display import SVG

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

Comment: What versions you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Please, keep in mind that the highest version supported by Anaconda is TF 2.1.0